# How do I write regression tests for a library built with webpack?

Tags: webpack, intern

I'm thinking of building our code with Webpack and babel, so we can mix ES6 dependencies with pre-existing AMD dependencies, and also continue supporting IE11, due to business requirements.

Our regression tests are essentially:

- one javascript test file for unit testing each class
- one HTML file for each custom element, with a javascript file to run WebDriver tests against it

This works well with Intern, where you just list all the javascript test files in your Intern configuration.  But it doesn't sound practical with Webpack, because it effectively makes hundreds of entry points.

Is the solution just to have a test-index.js type file that requires (i.e. includes) all the test javascript files, and then combine all the HTML test files into a single Storybook type "app"?  Or is there something simpler?

Answer (score 1):

As you point out, having tens or hundreds of entry points can lead to very long build times. I've generally found that bundling all the tests into a single bundle and having Intern load that as suite gives the best experience.

```js
// intern.json
{
  "suites": "build/unit_tests.js"
}
```

You can also encode the list of tests in the webpack config rather than having to manually create something like a `test-index.js` file.

```js
// webpack.config.js
const { sync: glob } = require('glob');
module.exports = {
  entry: glob('tests/unit/**/*.js'),
  output: {
    filename: 'unit_tests.js'
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.   I guess that's actually the easy part, the harder part for me is combining all my HTML test files.

Comment: Could you describe in a bit more detail how your are structured? Are these run as functional tests?

Comment: Yes, we're testing a bunch of custom elements, which (in Intern terminology) generally each have one unit test and one functional test, i.e. two javascript files and one HTML file.

Comment: Which HTML files are you combining? You shouldn't need to use webpack for functional tests (the tests or support files), unless you want to generate a single test page for all of the functional tests to use.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid combining HTML files, but I need to do *something* because IE11 does not support ES6 module format, nor ES6 syntax.  Recently though I'm thinking of making the tests run via requirejs-babel/es6! rather than webpack..  There's probably a performance hit etc., but it doesn't matter because they are just tests.

Comment: Functional tests don't run _in_ the browser, and a functional test page can load a component in the same way that it would be loaded in a normal application page. I mean, if the component is normally loadable in IE, it will b fine in a functional test. Unit tests are where things get trickier, although they don't generally involve custom HTML pages.

Comment: Right, but HTML files need to run in the browser.  And that's complicated when they load a mixture of AMD and ES6 modules.

Comment: That does make things tricky. Why does the HTML need to load both AMD and ES6, though?

Comment: This is the whole point of my original question.  We have a large AMD application with AMD dependencies and I want to add some ES6 dependencies.  And the regression tests need to keep working.

Comment: Any chance you could post a notional example somewhere of what your tests look like, including the mix of AMD and ES6?

Comment: See for example all the HTML files in https://github.com/ibm-js/deliteful/tree/master/tests/functional.  That's all AMD right now, but imagine if I changed (for example) https://github.com/ibm-js/deliteful/blob/master/Button.js to an ES6 module.

Comment: Ah, I see the issue now. Hmmm...yeah, testing the unbuilt source in IE would be problematic. Could you build a single module that loaded and exported all of the widgets, and use that in the functional test pages?

Comment: I think it's problematic in all browsers due to the mixture of AMD and ES6 module format.   But yeah, as you said, I'm going to make a single bundle with all my code and use it in all the HTML test pages.  Plus (as you mentioned) another bundle for the unit tests.

Note that my quest to use RequireJS and an es6! plugin failed because of RequireJS internal errors, as I listed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60199058/how-should-a-requirejs-transpilation-plugin-return-its-result.

Comment: You could try SystemJS, which also supports both ES6 and AMD, although the bundle will probably be more efficient.

Comment: Agreed.  About setting suites[] to a webpack bundle, I think it works in the simple case, but will fail if there are chunks (ex: there are top level bundles unit_test.js and app.js that both depend on 0.js).  In that case, unit_test.js will load asynchronously (in the browser) so intern needs to know when it has finished loading.

Comment: I agree, chunks would be problematic. I wonder if Intern could implement an async suite registration facility similar to how plugins currently work. That would depend on some synchronous execution happening in the initial bundle; I'll have to experiment.