# How should a RequireJS transpilation plugin return its result?

Tags: requirejs

Transpilation plugins like [es6!](https://github.com/mikach/requirejs-babel/blob/master/es6.js), [es!](https://github.com/SHOPMACHER/requirejs-es2015/blob/master/es.js), and [cs!](https://github.com/requirejs/require-cs/blob/master/cs.js) are more complicated than simple plugins like `text!` because they return javascript modules that have their own dependencies.

Specifically, the code I've seen loads the specified file through XHR, transforms it, and then returns the result via a call like

```js
onload.fromText("define(['foo', 'bar', ...");
```

That works fine for small test cases but throws a "Mismatched anonymous define() module" exception when running in my actual app.  It's a race condition that happens when RequireJS is simultaneously processing a bunch of normal JS requires at the same time as evaluating a bunch of plugin requires.

Is this just a RequireJS bug, or is the plugin doing it wrong? Or, is it just not supported?  Despite multiple transpilation plugin examples on the web, the [RequireJS doc on that error](https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch) says that

> If you use the loader plugins or anonymous modules (modules that call define() with no string ID) but do not use the RequireJS optimizer to combine files together, this error can occur.

Comment: Can you show the plugin code?

Comment: Check the first three links (especially the first two) in my question.